# How to actualize Django Template with get_context_data

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I need your help in order to know How I can actualize my `Django template` from `get_context_data`.

I have this class in my view :

```
class IdentitySocieteResumeView(LoginRequiredMixin,TemplateView) :

    template_name = 'Identity_Societe_Resume.html'
    model = Societe

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs) :

        context_data = super(IdentitySocieteResumeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        id = self.kwargs['id']
        societe = get_object_or_404(Societe, pk=id)

        obj = Societe.objects.filter(Nom=societe.Nom, SIRET=societe.SIRET, SIREN=societe.SIREN, Ville=societe.Ville)

        if obj:
            sc_obj = obj[0]

            NIU = lib.Individu_Recherche.NIUGeneratorSociete(ModelBase=societe)

            societe.NumeroIdentification = NIU
            societe.save()

            context_data['queryset'] = obj

        return context_data
```

And this important function in `lib.Individu_Recherche` :

```
def NIUGeneratorSociete(ModelBase) :

    create_year_temp = str(ModelBase.Creation.year)
    create_year_temp2 = str(create_year_temp.split(" "))
    create_year = create_year_temp2[4] + create_year_temp2[5]

    ''' A process which let to generate NumeroIdentification '''

    NumeroIdentification = force_text('%s-%s%s-%s-%s-%s' % ('E', create_year, create_month, create_city, key, create_country_id))

    return NumeroIdentification
```

Part of my template :

```
{% block content %}

    <div class="title_subtitle_space"></div>

    <div class="resume">

    {% for societe in queryset %}

        Votre société porte le numéro : <b> {{ societe.id}} </b> <p></p>
        N° identification attribué : <b>{{societe.NumeroIdentification}}</b> <br></br>

    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

I'm sure my template is loaded before to execute this function and I get in my template `NumeroIdentification = None` but in my database this field is well-filled.

**My question is :**  How I can display my variable `NumeroIdentification` with the good value in my template (value stored in my database) instead of `None` ?

If I press `Cmd + R` (MacOS Actualize), `NumeroIdentification` won't be `None` but a different value. I would like to get this value in my template the first time.

It's pretty easy with FBV, but with CBV I don't overcome to make it

**EDIT :**

I add my function `NIUGeneratorSociete` :

```
def NIUGeneratorSociete(ModelBase) :

    create_year_temp = str(ModelBase.Creation.year)
    create_year_temp2 = str(create_year_temp.split(" "))
    create_year = create_year_temp2[4] + create_year_temp2[5]

    create_month_temp = ModelBase.Creation.month
    if len(str(create_month_temp)) == 1 :
        create_month = '0' + str(create_month_temp)
    else :
        create_month = create_month_temp

    create_city = Villes[ModelBase.Ville]

    key_temp = randint(0,999999)
    if len(str(key_temp)) == 1 :
        key = '00000' + str(key_temp)
    elif len(str(key_temp)) == 2 :
        key = '0000' + str(key_temp)
    elif len(str(key_temp)) == 3 :
        key = '000' + str(key_temp)
    elif len(str(key_temp)) == 4 :
        key = '00' + str(key_temp)
    elif len(str(key_temp)) == 5 :
        key = '0' + str(key_temp)
    else :
        key = key_temp

    create_country = ModelBase.Pays
    create_country_id = None          
    if create_country == "CG" :
        create_country_id = 1
    else :
        create_country_id = 2

    NumeroIdentification = force_text('%s-%s%s-%s-%s-%s' % ('E', create_year, create_month, create_city, key, create_country_id))

    return NumeroIdentification
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this code is all kinds of confused. You're getting the same object in multiple different ways, and updating one copy but expecting the others to reflect the change.

You first get the relevant object as `societe`. Then for some reason you do another query on that model with all the fields of that object, to get a queryset consisting of one object. Then you do some manipulation of the original object and save it, but don't pass it to the context; instead you pass the queryset.

Your code can be simplified to just this:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs) :

    context_data = super(IdentitySocieteResumeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

    id = self.kwargs['id']
    societe = get_object_or_404(Societe, pk=id)

    NIU = lib.Individu_Recherche.NIUGeneratorSociete(societe)
    societe.NumeroIdentification = NIU
    societe.save()

    context_data['societe'] = societe

    return context_data
```

and the template:

```
{% block content %}
<div class="title_subtitle_space"></div>

    <div class="resume">

        Votre société porte le numéro : <b> {{ societe.id}} </b> <p></p>
        N° identification attribué : <b>{{societe.NumeroIdentification}}</b> <br></br>

    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

There are also some strange things going on in your library function. one is that you pass the object as the parameter ModelBase; although it doesn't matter what you call it, ModelBase is a class, but your parameter is an instance of your Societe class. You should call things what they are.

I can't correct that function though as it is clearly incomplete; all of `create_month`, `create_city`, `key`, `create_country_id` are undefined.

Finally, you should consider if any of this is appropriate. The update function is called from `get_context_data` in a normal GET request of your page; it would be very surprising for an object to be updated like this on a GET. Really this should be done on a POST only.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I understand all of my weird things. I have to change `get_context_data()` by `post()` in order to update my object and display this updated object in my template ?

Answer (score 1):

Lots of weird things going on here.

After `societe = get_object_or_404(Societe, pk=id)` you will have a Societe instance (or 404). You then filter Societe to get a list of objects that have the same properties at the instance you already received, and then fetch the first one of those. Why not just `obj = get_object_or_404(Societe, pk=id)` and skip the rest?

You then mix `obj`, `societe` and `sc_obj`. Your actions on one of them will be lost on the others until you fetch them again, which is probably why this works on refresh. Might be helpful to see your `Societe` model to confirm though.

Comment: You're right. I understand your reply and I don't know why I made these weird lines.